# cannot establish connection after reboot

Tags: python, paramiko, reboot

folks,

I faced an issue trying to reconnect to server after rebooting.. I saw other articles about similar issues but everything I try comes with the same error.

## Goal

Automatically reconnect to a server after reboot

## Script

```
ssh_client = SSHClient()
ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
ssh_client.connect(hostname=host,port=port, username=user, password=psw)
s = ssh_client.get_transport().open_session()
agent.AgentRequestHandler(s)

         try:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command, get_pty= True)
            get_output(stdout)
            channel = stdout.channel
            stdin.close()
            channel.shutdown_write()
            stdout_chunks = []
            stdout_chunks.append(channel.recv(len(channel.in_buffer)))
            while not channel.closed or channel.recv_ready() or channel.recv_stderr_ready():
                got_chunk = False
                readq, _, _ = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [])
                for c in readq:
                    if c.recv_ready():
                        stdout_chunks.append(channel.recv(len(c.in_buffer)))
                        got_chunk = True
                    if c.recv_stderr_ready():
                        stderr.channel.recv_stderr(len(c.in_stderr_buffer))
                        got_chunk = True
                    if not got_chunk \
                            and channel.exit_status_ready() \
                            and not channel.recv_stderr_ready() \
                            and not channel.recv_ready():
                        channel.shutdown_read()
                        channel.close()
                        break
            stdout.close()
            stderr.close()

        except (ConnectionResetError, SSHException):
            print('Connection died')
```

Error is cached by try catch block:

```
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
Connection died
```

Script which I running in a remote server ends with a reboot command:

```
/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Your code snippet is missing try.  Where is it?  Try placing it outside `ssh_client.connect()` to ensure you build the connection again from scratch.

Comment: it's just a copy paste mistake. Will edit my post. As you can see it's outside  @Hannu

Comment: After reboot, you usually need to start the httpd service and mysql service in order for web server to go up. check if that is your case.

Comment: these two services start automatically after every reboot. Also I connect via SSH so as far as I know server shouldnt be running httpd or mysqld in order to reconnect. Correct me if I am wrong :) @Kosem

Comment: I do not understand why these two lines does not help  s=ssh.get_transport().open_session() #get 'ssh' transport and open sessions assigned to 's' variable
paramiko.agent.AgentRequestHandler(s) #call in 's' to the forwarding agent for current ssh session

Comment: Your updated code still does not explain why are you getting "Connection died" many times. Is there some loop in your code? Where is the loop? + Can you connect with any SSH client after the reconnect?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yeah thats kind of strange. There is no any loop here.. I ran a command which executes a script in a remote server.. Everything works ok but then it reach restart line it cannot reconnect... And yes I can reconnect manually, or if i run this script again it also works.. till that line of reboot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will post this as an answer as it is too long to be explained in a comment.

Your code is still missing parts as we do not know how you call the try/except structure and what happens when the exception is caught.  However, if I may make a guess from your indent is that if an exception is caught, you will repeat try/except somehow.

You seem to rely on the channel closed status in your logic but there is an underlying layer in the form of a TCP socket. When you reboot the server, your channel dies but so does the TCP layer. In your exception handling you will need to recreate this.

I would try something like this:

```
try:
    ...
    ...
    ...
    stdout.close()
    stderr.close()
except (...):
    sleep(2)  # to prevent a busyloop when your server is rebooting      
    try:
        ssh_client.close()  # Close the connection just in case it is alive
    except:
        pass    # We do not care if it succeeds or fails
    counter = 0     # optional
    while True:
        sleep(2)    # to prevent a busyloop when your server is rebooting
        counter += 1
        if counter > X:
            print("server permanently down, exiting")
            exit (1)
        try:
            ssh_client.connect(hostname=host,port=port, username=user, password=psw)
            s = ssh_client.get_transport().open_session()
            break    # We have a liftoff
        except:
            pass     # Server not responding yet. Try again.
```

(I did not test the above code, just wrote it here to give the idea. There might be typos in there)

You can ignore the counter part. I generally use a counter to prevent programs from trying until the cows come home if the server is down for long term. If you want to keep trying, remove these.  If you use them, just set X high enough to allow the server plenty of time to reboot and then some.

The key part is recreating your TCP connection after an error and only leaving the error handler when you have a working connection again.

We attempt to close the existing connection just in case it is still there to avoid exhausting server resources if the problem is not in the connection dropping but we do not care if it succeeds or fails.  Then we recreate the connection from scratch.

This may or may not work in your case as we do not know from your code how you re-enter this after an exception - and you do not seem to be sure either based on your comments.

Comment: thanks. Fixed it by adding ssh_client.get_transport() is not None to if stattement and if yes reconnect.

Comment: Good that it works. This might not be the bullet proof way, though.  If this is a busy environment, eventually the unexpected will happen and your server dies between your new if statement and the rest of the code. Transport was up when checked but not anymore when you try to send.   Now your client would again end in the exception handler.   Maybe your code works in this case as well if the next iteration hits your `get_transport()` check. Just something to keep in mind.